# ClasspathXMLApplicationContext working in spring

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring, i am trying to understand the statement "ClassPathXMLApplication context searches for xml in all jars in classpath".

So in an application

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myBeans.xml");
```

will it search in all the dependent jars for this myBeans.xml?

Comment: Can you please share the project structure to understand where is myBeans.xml is placed, ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myBeans.xml");  works fine if placed under src/resources/myBeans.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work , but you are not giving path of file right , since it is in a jar in classpath , you have to give something like this

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:**/myBeans.xml");
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to understand how to pass the application bean context using constructors.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("myBeans.xml");
```

works fine if placed under src/resources/myBeans.xml , because

The classpath root is **WEB-INF/classes**, and **src/main/resources** goes there, together with **src/main/java**